# spring oauth obtain user details from token

Tags: java, spring, oauth, netflix-zuul

i want to use spring and oauth and so far it seemed to work.
now i added a zuul proxy that is configured like that:

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    sso:
      home:
        secure: false
        path: /,/**/*.html
    client: 
      accessTokenUri: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/oauth/authorize
      clientId: webapp
      clientSecret: secret
    resource:
      id: apis
      userInfoUri: http://${authserver.hostname}:${authserver.port}/${authserver.contextPath}/rest/me
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

whenever i try to access an resource server it tries to verify my authentication but my authserver endpoint seems to return text/html instead of json.

```
 Created GET request for "http://localhost:8091/userauth/rest/me"
2015-11-24 14:07:12.275 DEBUG 3601 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate   : Setting request Accept header to  [application/json, application/*+json]
2015-11-24 14:07:12.287 DEBUG 3601 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate   : GET request for "http://localhost:8091/userauth/rest/me" resulted in 200 (OK)
2015-11-24 14:07:12.288  INFO 3601 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.c.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices        : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException, Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
```

i already forced json and when accessing auth server directly via curl i get json formatted principal.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/me", produces = "application/json")
public Principal getCurrentLoggedinUser(Principal user){
    return user;
}
```

any ideas how to send json to my zuul proxy so it can verify my authentication?